# NSString stringWithContentsOfURL crashes application when host is unreacheable

Tags: ios, networking, nsstring

It is really tricky problem, I use code as below:

```
NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *guideText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

The code works like a charm unless I bring server which URL points down. It issues about 1 minute pause, but then the method call returns with an error. So far so good. It behaves same way when I run app in simulator or on device under debugger. But if I run the program on device without debugger, it crashes after the pause. I tried wrap the code in @try/@catch, but nothing helps. Actually debugger doesn't see any problems, so here is some mystery for me. I tried to put some guard code as below:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
if ([NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil])
    // here code above       
[request release];
```

The code behaves exactly as previous. Program pauses here for a minute and then goes through normally, unless it runs on device without debugger.

Comment: Program pauses it is  because of synchronous request. Can just try NSURLConnection delegate for getting the response ?

Comment: Can u upload the crash report from your device? Also, you can try `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest` method.

Comment: Some answer would be nice